# Get records from mySQL table that have certain ID set, and it's the only record in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table that looks like that:

[image]

I want to pull all product_id from such table that have certain category_id set, AND this record is the only one for that product ID. (if there are two records for product_id with any category_id, it shouldn't be included).

I tried something like that:

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM `products_categories` 
WHERE category_id = 541 
AND HAVING COUNT(product_id) = 1;
```

But that returns a syntax error that I can't figure out. Anyone can advice what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: `HAVING` is used for groups and you don't have a `GROUP BY` here

Comment: So I should be using GROUP BY before HAVING? I wrote something like that: SELECT product_id FROM `products_categories` WHERE category_id = 541 GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(product_id) = 1 but it returns nothing while I checked and there is a product_id meeting conditions I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Does the table with distinct `product_id` values exists?

Comment: You almost done with your query. If you just omit where clause you will get all lonely products in your table `SELECT product_id FROM products_categories GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`

Comment: Akina has already posted a solution that returns correct values - thanks to everyone for discussion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT product_id 
FROM products_categories t1
WHERE category_id = 541 
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                 FROM products_categories t2 
                 WHERE t1.product_id = t2.product_id 
                   AND t1.category_id <> t2.category_id );
```